# How to add numbers in between string in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which includes strings and integers.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 'turtle', 4, 5, 1, 'dog', 2, 'cow', 3, 4]
```

This is my expected output.

```
[3, 'turtle', 10, 'dog', 2, 'cow', 7]
```

I tried using for loop, but I can't seem to achieve my desired result.

Comment: Please update the question with the `for` loop you've tried so we can help see how you're stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [1, 2, "turtle", 4, 5, 1, "dog", 2, "cow", 3, 4]

out = []
for v, g in groupby(mylist, lambda k: isinstance(k, str)):
    if v:
        out.extend(g)
    else:
        out.append(sum(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 'turtle', 10, 'dog', 2, 'cow', 7]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!